# How to make one-way restriction in n:m association?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have N:M association in Sequelize between `User` and `TrainerProp` (User properities). Here is simplified example:

```
/**
 * User
 */
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    // USER ATTRIBUTES... NOT IMPORTANT
});

User.associate = models => {
    // User have many TrainerProps
    User.belongsToMany(TrainerProp, {
        through: 'user_trainerProp',
        foreignKey: 'user_id'
    });
};

/**
 * TrainerProp
 */
const TrainerProp = sequelize.define('TrainerProp', {
    // TRAINER PROP ATTRIBUTES... NOT IMPORTANT
});

TrainerProp.associate = models => {
    // TrainerProp belongs to many Users
    TrainerProp.belongsToMany(User, {
        through: 'user_trainerProp',
        foreignKey: 'trainerProp_id',
        onDelete: 'restrict',
        onUpdate: 'restrict'
    });
};

/**
 * user_trainerProp table (n:m)
 */
const user_trainerProp = sequelize.define('user_trainerProp', {
    trainerProp_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

As you can see, I made restriction onUpdate and onDelete on `Trainer`, so when I try to delete `TrainerProp` what is used in table `user_trainerProp` it will throw `ForeignKeyConstraintError`.

My problem is, that when I try to delete `User` what have some `TrainerProps` I am getting restricted too. I expected, when I delete `User`, all rows in `user_trainerProp` will get removed too and I don't get errors...

How to achieve this?